# How to display a table which has a sorted dictionary in qstudio?

Tags: kdb

I have a table with a column which can sometimes contain strings and sometimes elements of the form `` `s#(`s#`timestamp$())!`symbol$() ``. However, whenever I run a select from the table using q studio, it gives the response `` (trueb;kx.c$Flip@eeaaafe;`sym1`sym2) `` even though it works perfectly fine in the q console. I tried disabling the wrapping but then it just gives the result `([] column_names)`.

**Sample code:**

```
q)([]col1:`row_1`row_2`row_3;col2:(118718;`s#`s#2018.04.04D07:30:00.000000000 2018.04.04D07:45:00.000000000!`value1`value2;`s#`s#2011.02.03D00:00:00.000000000 2018.06.06D00:00:00.000000000!123456 0N))
col1  col2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
row_1 118718
row_2 `s#`s#2018.04.04D07:30:00.000000000 2018.04.04D07:45:00.000000000!`value1`value2
row_3 `s#`s#2011.02.03D00:00:00.000000000 2018.06.06D00:00:00.000000000!123456 0N
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample table & query for which you experience this? With SO questions, it's always best to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Of course this doesn't have to be classified production data, just a small example that illustrates your problem succinctly

Comment: @JonathonMcMurray I've given a small sample table above.

Comment: @N M I mean a piece of code that can be executed in KDB+ i.e. at a `q)` prompt. See here: http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/faq-listbox/#how-to-post-test-data-on-the-k4-list

What you've posted here isn't particularly useful to anyone trying to replicate as it can't be loaded back into KDB

Comment: With the sample code edited in by Thomas, I get the table displayed normally in qStudio

Comment: Thanks. I found that the issue was the `s# attribute and that this bug had been reported and fixed in 1.43

Answer (score 2):

The reason this didn't work was that the java interface interprets the result as a different type when it's sorted. Perhaps this is fixed in newer API versions. Either way as Jonathon mentions it is fixed in qStudio version 1.43 and up.

If anyone else finds bugs please report to:
http://www.timestored.com/contact
As I don't always check SO.